# Mapping n variables to the surface of an n+1-dimensional cross polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes

I'm looking for a function that maps n variables to points on the surface of an n+1-dimensional [cross polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope).  For example, given one variable, the function would return a point on the perimeter of a square.  Given two variables, it would return a point on the surface of an octahedron.  Given three variables, it would return a point on one of the facets of a 16-cell.  And so on.

Failing that, does anyone know a formula or algorithm for random point picking on the surface of a unit n-ball in the L1-norm?  (These are also cross polytopes.)  There are formulas for [picking uniformly distributed random points **within** a ball](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallPointPicking.html), but I haven't been able to find one for picking points **on** its facets.

This is for an agent-based simulation in which the points on these objects represent a player's legal moves.  A continuous function that does one of the above things would make it fairly easy to search for optimal moves.

Comment: You have to be more specific on what conditions of the map you seek. Must it be surjective? Can I map all points to a corner?

Based on your last paragraph, I think you seek a continuous parametrization of the surface. But this should be straightforward to do from a sphere: Just take the vector and project onto the surface by normalization...

Comment: Do you need uniform distribution on the surface?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment: the surface of the cross polytope is given by 
$\{x : \vert x \vert_1 = 1 \}$.

Thus, the map $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n)/(x_1+\dots+x_n)$,
almost does the job, but it requires a different number of input variables.
By composing this with a map that sends a parametrization of the $n-1$- dimensional sphere $S^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, you get such a map you seek.